# Finiteness of embedded clause in "Susan seems to have gone"

Tags: syntax, morphosyntax

My textbook flags the above mentioned phrase as non-finite but it clearly seems to indicate tense. After all, alterations like "have eaten", "have been eating", "have had been eating", "having been about to eat" are possible. So, is the author wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: By "embedded clause" I'm assuming you mean _to have gone_. The _to_ clearly marks an infinitive clause and infinitive clauses are always non-finite.; that's what _infinitive_ **means**. As to the rest, English only has tense on inflected verbs with subjects; tense has something to do with time, but it is not determined by time -- we can speak about the present, the past, and the future without using any tense at all, and frequently do  in English. Infinitives and participles can refer to anything.

Comment: Finite past tense means the same as non-finite "have".  So, you and the author are both right.  In 1966, T. R. Hofmann gave a formalization of this with a rule "past tense replacement", and McCawley incorporated this into his own analysis in *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.

Comment: The perfect tense can combine with preterite and present tense but can also occur in clauses without inflectional tense, as in your example.

Comment: There are two embedded non-finite clauses: the infinitival "to have gone", which contains the further embedded past-participial clause "gone" -- the latter functioning as catenative complement of "have".

Comment: @BillJ Presumably, if you're giving a CamGEL style analysis, there are three, no? "to have gone", "have gone" and "gone"

Comment: @Araucaria But "have gone" is just the VP of the clause "to have gone".

Comment: @BillJ Oh yes. In that analysis, isn't "to have gone" a VP as opposed to a clause? (Consider, for example "For John to have gone without saying goodbye is very unusual")

Comment: @Araucaria In isolation, yes, but in a sentence, "to have gone" is a clause (albeit subjectless of course) functioning as catenative complement of "seem". The subordinator "to" is just a marker for VPs of infinitival clauses, not a clause. In your example, "for" is the marker for the entire clause "For John to have gone without saying goodbye", in which there is the sub clause "gone without saying goodbye".

Comment: @BillJ Ah, yes. I see. Had missed the sentence in the title.

Comment: @jlawler if infinitives (which by definition are non-finite) and participles can in fact refer to any semantic tense, then you will have to explain "finiteness" without reference to tense. Otherwise it's circular, no?